# Unit testing a nonblocking method (asynchronous testing)

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing

I have a very simple `Check`class which has a blocking `waitForCondition()` method.  This method is blocking.  I want to create some unit tests for this method.  First, the method should return when the condition is met.  Second, the method should return when it is interrupted.

Internally the `Check` class has an `ArrayBlockingQueue` and calls its `take()` method, so my test is really about having coded the logic for the condition correctly (as it should be).
In the application, data for the `Check` class is fed by another thread via an `InputData` method.  The `InputData` method executes the logic on incoming data and places a dummy object in the ArrayBlockingQueue when the condition is met.  This should cause `waitForCondition()` to return.

So my first thought is I can test the `InputData` by mocking and check to see the dummy object is added to the queue when the condition is met.  This would require changing the design of the class, since the queue is a private data member (unless it is possible to mock private data).  Instead of `InputData` adding directly to the queue when the condition is met, it would have to call something which could be mocked.

But then there is the problem of checking the `waitForCondition()` methods themselves, given that `InputData` is functioning correctly. It's really simply code:

```
try {
        myArrayBlockingQueue.take();
        return true;
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        return false;
    }
```

So I'm wondering if it's worth the imagined trouble: a test which creates another thread with a `Check`, calls its `waitForCondition()`, then returns something when it's done.  Perhaps, using an Executor service.  The fuzzy part is how to synchronize the `assertTrue(...)`.  I found this [article on asynchronous testing](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+extreme+programming/Chapter+4.+JUnit/4.15+Testing+Asynchronous+Methods/) which looks like it might do the trick.

Summary of question:

1. Should I change the design to test the logic in `InputData()` and if so, how?
2. Should I leave out the test of `waitForCondition()` as long as `InputData()` is tested?
3. Or is it better to just do what needs to be done (a somewhat complicated unit test) and test `waitForCondition()` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inject the instance of ArrayBlockingQueue in the constructor of the Check class, then your test can inject the appropriate value in the middle of the test.

Then you can run the unit test with a timeout, and fail if it doesn't return within 100ms or so.

Comment: +1  Interesting idea.  The injected Queue could be mocked to throw an InterruptedException under certain test conditions, wait a long time, etc...

Comment: Great idea.  I added a constructor to the `Check` class, for testing purposes, which injects the Queues as you suggested.  Then, I was able to test all the public methods by setting up and reading the actual queues (not mocks) directly.  I only needed to use a mock to test the InterruptedException.  Using Mockito: `when(queueMock.take()).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());`  So, in this case, we could test without any asynchronous/timing issues at all.

Comment: This is a great solution if the number of blocking objects is small and your code is structured so they can be injected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nice link!  I faced some similar problems, and maybe that link is a better way to go than what I did.  (I'm also interested to see what other answers appear to this question - it's a good question)

If you don't mind changing (at least *temporarily*) your actual code (yes, this is not a usual unit-test practice!) you can do something I called ["Error Injection"](http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.com/2011/12/testing-error-handling-in-complex-code.html).

In my implementation, you create a class that reads from properties (or a Map) to "do something funny" at a specific unique point.  e.g. your properties might say

```
myClass.myMethod.blockingQueueTake = interrupt:
myClass.myLongCalculation = throw: java.lang.ArithmeticException(Failed to converge)
```

In your code, you add testing lines, e.g. right before your `queue.take()`, add

```
TestSimulator.doCommand("myClass.myMethod.blockingQueueTake");
```

The advantage is that everything is happening in real-real code, not some Mock, which can get really hairy.  (In my case, the SW was older, not written/designed for unit-testing, so making a Mock was very difficult)  The disadvantage is that you will probably want to remove or comment out the code afterwards.  So it really isn't a continuous-integration type unit test, it's more of a one-time really serious reality debug.  So, I admit, it's far far from ideal, but, it did find a bunch of bugs for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a "test runner" class to run the asserts in a loop. The loop would run the asserts in a try/catch. The exception handler would simply try to run the asserts again until a timeout has expired. I recently wrote a blog post about this technique. The example is written in groovy, but the concept should be easily adaptable for Java.

http://www.greenmoonsoftware.com/2013/08/asynchronous-functional-testing/